# breeze: querying local cache when using client-side model

Tags: breeze

Consider the below code. It works fine when getting data from the server. I have a custom data adapter (staffManagemetnService) which creates client-side entities from the json returned by the server.

However, if I make a call to executeQueryLocally, it fails and raises the following exception: `Cannot find an entityType for resourceName: 'GetInternalResourcesByCompetence'.  Consider adding an 'EntityQuery.toType' call to your query or calling the MetadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName method to register an entityType for this resourceName`

```
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('GetInternalResourcesByCompetence').withParameters(parameters);

        var result = self.manager.executeQueryLocally(query.using(dataService.staffManagementService));
        if (result) {
            return $q.resolve(result);
        } else {
            return this.manager.executeQuery(query.using(dataService.staffManagementService))
                .then(function (data) {
                    return data.results;
                })
               .catch(function (err) {
                   logError('Restrieving resources days off failed', err, true);
               });
        }
```

I'm not sure what this means. Should it not work out-of-the-box since I've specifically asked breeze to use the custom dataAdapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to different between resource names and entity type names. Resource names are usually part of an endpoint and in plural (eg `orders`). Type names are typically singular (eg `order`).

Locally breeze cannot do much with the resource name, since it won't call the endpoint. Instead you ask for a certain entity type name.

You can map an entityType to a resourcename using the `setEntityTypeForResourceName` function:

```
metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName('Speakers', 'Person');
```

See chapter "Resources names are not EntityType names" and the following chapters here: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-locally

Comment: yes, you'right. In the end I retrieved the entity from cache and then filtered out the results using a simple filter function. But filters cannot be applied using withParams.